# Chaining array of strings into file C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I have three arrays of strings and i want to combine them and write them to a file (S1[]+S2[]+S3[]).
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: There are two requirements here, to combine the three arrays, and to write them to file. Are you simply combining them to write their contents to file? i.e. Are you sure you actually need to combine them?

Comment: What kind of a file is that? A plain textual file? A binary file? Should each string be separated by a new line? Should individial arrays be separated in some way?

Comment: Are you specifically wanting to combine the arrays before writing them? Or your main goal is that all should just end up in the file?

Comment: I want to combine them because i don't want to write three times to a file. those are big arrays and its a lot of IO time.. and it's a txt file.

Comment: @aharon: The only thing you will get by combining them is unnecessary allocation of a large object. There is no difference if you write 300 lines to a file, or write 100 lines three times. You can specify a larger output buffer size when creating your `FileStream`, if this concerns you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you simply want to combine the arrays to write them to a text file . . .

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter("MyFile.txt"))
{
    foreach(var item in arr1.union(arr2).union(arr3))
       writer.WriteLine(item)
}
```

This answer has provoked a "*Write once* is faster than *write many* debate", I'd like to address the issue in the body of the answer.

Firstly, either method for small amounts of data isn't going to make much difference one way or the other. Really, on modern systems for sizes in the megabyte range (and possibly larger) there won't be much of a performance difference (at this point I haven't benchmarked anything, but I'll put my money on straight to disk IO).

The issue really is one of scalability, if you've a system under load, and you've a couple of 100mbs of data, then the "buffer first" method will be drastically slower, you're setting yourself up for a whole world of pain with OS page faults, especially if your data is spread across several pages, you'l constantly be swapping in and out memory pages, which will slow down not just your app, but the entire machine.

I'll now write some code to benchmark both approaches, I'll post the code and my results shortly.

And the results are in, there really isn't much of a performance difference. For 12k of data * 100 writes both come in (on my machine, obviously) at approx 1 minute 38 seconds. On repeated runs the direct to disk is faster, but never by more than half a second.

The real surprise was `File.WriteAllLines` and `File.AppendAllLines` which took 8 minutes 35 seconds. I didn't try unioning the arrays and calling `File.WriteAllLines` once (available since .net 4.0), but I reckon it would be better, the delay is probably opening the file multiple times.

**Given that the differences are (as predicted) negligible for small amounts of data, I'd opt to go with the simpler code, and write the strings directly to file.**

I haven't run it more than a couple of times, because it takes time, if someone else wants to set this up to run over night and get more accurate trends, please be my guest.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var arr1 = BuildArr(1000000);
        var arr2 = BuildArr(1000000);
        var arr3 = BuildArr(1000000);

        DoDirectToDisk(arr1, arr2, arr3);
        DoBuffered(arr1, arr2, arr3);
        DoWriteLines(arr1, arr2, arr3);

    }

    private static void DoWriteLines(string[] arr1, string[] arr2, string[] arr3)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\WriteLines.txt", arr1);
            File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\WriteLines.txt", arr1);
            File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\WriteLines.txt", arr1);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Write Lines {0}", sw.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void DoBuffered(string[] arr1, string[] arr2, string[] arr3)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                foreach (var item in arr1.Union(arr2).Union(arr3))
                    writer.WriteLine(item);
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\buffered.txt", writer.ToString());
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Buffered {0}", sw.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void DoDirectToDisk(string[] arr1, string[] arr2, string[] arr3)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Direct.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var item in arr1.Union(arr2).Union(arr3))
                    writer.WriteLine(item);
            }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Direct To Disk took {0}", sw.Elapsed);
    }
```

Last run output was

Direct To Disk took 00:01:38.2458291
Buffered 00:01:39.0499939
Write Lines 00:08:35.5900614

Comment: its a lot of IO time to write every line seperately!

Comment: @aharon: Why do you say that?

Comment: @aharon: You're overly concerned by the number of writes, this isn't a problem. It's better to write 10 or 10,000 lines individually than it is to buffer them in to single strings to reduce the number of writes. Honestly, don't try to second guess what's fast and what's not when it comes to the file system. Write the simplest code you can and worry about performance if it's too slow (but this won't be, I promise).

Comment: Because you are accessing the hard disk each time instead of once... to your second comments- the buffer is in the RAM which is faster then the HD by a 1000 times.

Comment: @aharon: No, you don't. You have windows sitting between your program and the hard disk, you've hard disk controllers sitting between windows and the physcial disk (and probably lots more stuff going on that I don't know about). Windows does lots of complicated stuff to minimise the amount of Disk IO that happens, then you've on board write buffering on the hard disk. What actually happens is far beyond my knowledge, but in the end the mental model you have that **1 call to `WriteLine` = 1 hit to the hard disk** is hugely incorrect (sorry, but it is).

Comment: Eh, can whoever downvoted care to tell me why? I'd like to know what's wrong with my answer so I can fix it. We're all here to lean after all, thanks :)

Comment: @aharon: I've updated my answer with benchmark timings and sample code to get them. As predicted the differences are negligible, in this instance I'd go with the solution with the simplest code. **NB** Never make assumptions about performance, and never go out of your way to write "performant" code without benchmarking and seeing do you actually need it _"Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- DonaldKnuth_

Comment: I benchmaked myself and you were write. The resutes were the same. I just hope it would be like that for the long term. I need to run this function for some thousend of time so the performeces does counts. Tanks!

Comment: @aharon: It'll be fine, the more data you have the better it will perform. This is 20 (or so) years of professional experience talking :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the *best* way, but one of he simpler would be this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, S1.Union(S2).Union(S3));
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Description

Assuming you want to write all your Array´s content to a TextFile
you can do this using

- `List<string>` (System.Collections.Generic namespace)
- `FileStream` (System.IO namespace)
- `StreamWriter` (System.IO namespace)

#### Sample

```
string[] a1 = new string[] { "Text1", "Text2" };
string[] a2 = new string[] { "Another Text1", "Another Text2" };

List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(a1);
list.AddRange(a2);

using (FileStream str = new FileInfo(@"C:\MyFilePath.txt").OpenWrite())
{
    StreamWriter writter = new StreamWriter(str);
    writter.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));
    writter.Close();
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN: List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)
- [MSDN: FileStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)
- [MSDN: StreamWriter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ:

```
var s1 = new string[0]; var s2 = new string[0]; var s3 = new string[0];

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("c:\temp.text.txt")) 
{   
  writer.Write(s1.Union(s2).Union(s3).Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, var) => current + var)); 
}
```

Comment: This might be unnecessary if the only intent is to write them to a file. And using the original symbols (`S1`, `S2`) would make it clearer for the OP, IMHO.

Comment: `Aggregate` here is completely unnecessary, it will concatenate each array element onto a string, leading to lots of memory allocations, when it would be _far_ simpler to just loop and write once for each array element.

Comment: What is more efficient, making the memory allocations and call writer.Write once? Or reducing the allocations and looping the Write call? I have no idea and I guess it make little difference until you are deal ing with large valumes of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`System.IO.File.AppendAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691.aspx) method to append all strings line in specific file.

Comment: It supported by .NET 4.0 and later versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;

var combinedList = a1.ToList().AddRange(a2);
var combinedArray = list.ToArray();

using (var stream = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
    stream.Write(combinedArray, 0, combinedArray.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the strings together:

```
var allStrings = new List<string>();
allStrings.AddRange(S1);
allStrings.AddRange(S2);
allStrings.AddRange(S3);
```

Where S1, S2 and S3 are the string arrays you refer to.

To write into a standard text file with all strings joined by spaces (as an example):

```
string text = string.Join(" ", allStrings.ToArray());
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Path\To\Some\File.txt", text);
```